# How can I make a values out of two groups that have seperate normal distributions?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am doing a graduation research and got stuck for two weeks solving this problem. I am not a expert in mathematics so I might use the wrong expressions.

I have sensor data that measures the movement of the x, y, and z axis. Basically, I am only interested in the amount of movement/activity. So I do not need to know any actual rotation or translation/movement.

And I want to divide this movement into 2 groups: movement and fixed. I have observed if the sensor was moving or not. Here is a example of my data:

[movement vs. fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mAW1.png)

And as you can see it is obvious when the sensor was mostly moving and when it was mostly fixed. Now I am trying to make values that significantly distinguish both groups. And this calculated values should fit in a normal distribution that do not overlap. This would be a acceptable result, although it would be better when they do not overlap at all:

[two standard distributions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iNS0.png)

And I have tried many things to get the wanted result but none of them work. Here are some examples of what I tried.

- absolute gradient x axis + absolute gradient y axis + absolute gradient z axis.
- absolute rollingsum x + absolute rollingsum y + absolute rollingsum z

[absolute gradient x axis .....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynt9s.png)

But no matter what I try, I do not get distributions that do not overlap (a lot).

Does anyone know how I can get values that will result in not or just a little overlapping distributions?

I hope I was clear. Greetings

Comment: What is the vertical axis on your first illustration? Somewhere around $0$ on that scale seems to provide separation. If so, why? If not, why not? Answers might help to make your measurements and objectives more clear.

Comment: It is the measured "Gravitational acceleration". So the sum of the three axis is mostly 1.  It is coincidence that the 0 seems to separate. And I know a lot about the sensor and geodesics but it is not about that. I need to translate the obvious fixed and moving of the sensor to some values to recognize data from other sensors. So after I am able to give them separate distributions I can apply these values on other sensor data to recognize and validate the movement.